# button and movie clip actionscript 2.0 for flash

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, movieclip

I'm extremely new to flash, having just started using it this semester for a class. I'm putting together a fairly simple "portfolio slideshow" (it's a mock up for a website) for an assignment, but ran into some issues.

I have two sections on the "home page"; still images and time-based files. Each file is activated by a button (a thumbnail of the image). Ideally, when you click on the thumbnail, it brings up the image, or the movie. I got the buttons to work fine for navigating through the still images, but I can't get them to work for the movie files. I want to be able to click the button and have the movie file pop up. I have a feeling it has something to do with mistakes during importing the files, or just me not knowing the script.

Any ideas? =/

Sorry for any confusion. Explaining flash problems is pretty complicated...

In addition: I have the .fla if anyone needs better examples, and I am using Flash CS5. Thank you again for any help!  :)

And here is the script that is working for the buttons that go to still images, but isn't working when trying to go to video:

```
on (release) {
slides.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Slides is the instance name of the movie clip with all of the still images.

Comment: i'd like to take a look at the .fla, but i have flash cs4

Comment: Post a link to the fla, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of missing stops on the frames where each video file was.